# Unable to connect R rhdfs APIs with Hadoop Cluster, which is running on different IP address

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, rhadoop, bigdata

Add Hadoop Home

```
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_HOME"="ssh://root@192.168.10.70/home/easy/hadoop")
```

Set HADOOP CMD PATH

`Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CMD"="ssh://root@192.168.10.70/home/easy/hadoop/bin/hadoop"`)

```
Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME"="/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera")

Sys.setenv("HADOOP_STREAMING"="ssh://root@192.168.10.70/home/easy/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar")

Sys.setenv("HADOOP_LIB"="ssh://root@192.168.10.70/home/easy/hadoop/lib")
```

Load library rhdfs

```
library(rhdfs)
```

Initialize hdfs

```
hdfs.init()
```

Comment: Can you give us more details on the error message?